# Reading int values from array - Order incorrect when loading

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays

I am having an issue with reading files int values from an array if any one can help. These int are used to change the values of UILables on different views. Upto objectAtIndex:29 everything is OK after that the order is incorrcet and values are missing and I don't know why. I have tried to create an array for each view but this did not work. The code I use is below, if anyone can see an issue I would appreciate it.

```
-(NSString *) saveFilePath{

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefilee.plist"];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground: (UIApplication *) application{

    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:smaWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:medWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:larWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:halfBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:fullBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:smaSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:larSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:alcPop],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:hp],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:hc],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:bb],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:addUnit],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:borg],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:savedTenValue],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:addOne],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pinCid],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pinLag],//nil];

    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdsmaWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdmedWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdlarWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdhalfBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdfullBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdsmaSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdlarSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdalcPop],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdhp],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdhc],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdbb],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:svdaddUnit],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:savedTenValue],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:warningmessage],
    //[NSNumber numberWithInt:continueall],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:continueFemale],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:continueMale],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:svdpinLag],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:svdpinCid],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:svdTotal],



    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesmaWin],

    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malemedWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malelarWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malehalfBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malefullBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesmaSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malelarSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malealcPop],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malehp],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malehc],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malebb],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:maleaddUnit],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:maleborg],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesavedTenValue],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:maleaddOne],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malepinLag],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malepinCid],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malehalfpinCid],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malehalfpinLag],
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:maleaddOne],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdsmaWin],

    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdmedWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdlarWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdhalfBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdfullBotWin],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdsmaSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdlarSpi],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdalcPop],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdhp],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdhc],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdbb],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdaddUnit],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malewarningmessage],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:continueall],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:continueFemale],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:continueMale],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdTotal],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdpinLag],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:malesvdpinCid],

    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ukOrUsa],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:ukonce],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:usaonce],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:maleukonce],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:maleusaonce],nil];



    [values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [values release];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:count];
    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
    if (fileExists) {
        NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
        smaWin = [[values objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        medWin = [[values objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        larWin = [[values objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        halfBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
        fullBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:4] intValue];
        smaSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:5] intValue];
        larSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:6] intValue];
        alcPop = [[values objectAtIndex:7] intValue];
        hp = [[values objectAtIndex:8] intValue];
        hc = [[values objectAtIndex:9] intValue];
        bb = [[values objectAtIndex:10] intValue];
        addUnit = [[values objectAtIndex:11] intValue];
        borg = [[values objectAtIndex:12] intValue];
        savedTenValue  = [[values objectAtIndex:13] intValue];
        addOne = [[values objectAtIndex:14] floatValue];
        pinCid = [[values objectAtIndex:15] floatValue];
        pinLag = [[values objectAtIndex:16] floatValue];


        svdsmaWin = [[values objectAtIndex:17] intValue];
        svdmedWin = [[values objectAtIndex:18] intValue];
        svdlarWin = [[values objectAtIndex:19] intValue];
        svdhalfBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:20] intValue];
        svdfullBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:21] intValue];
        svdsmaSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:22] intValue];
        svdlarSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:23] intValue];
        svdalcPop = [[values objectAtIndex:24] intValue];
        svdhp = [[values objectAtIndex:25] intValue];
        svdhc = [[values objectAtIndex:26] intValue];
        svdbb = [[values objectAtIndex:27] intValue];
        svdaddUnit = [[values objectAtIndex:28] intValue];
        warningmessage = [[values objectAtIndex:29] intValue];
        //continueall = [[values objectAtIndex:30] intValue];
        continueFemale = [[values objectAtIndex:31] intValue];
        continueMale = [[values objectAtIndex:32] intValue];
        svdpinLag = [[values objectAtIndex:33] floatValue];
        svdpinCid = [[values objectAtIndex:34] floatValue];
        svdTotal = [[values objectAtIndex:35] floatValue];


        malesmaWin = [[values objectAtIndex:36] intValue];
        malemedWin = [[values objectAtIndex:37] intValue];
        malelarWin = [[values objectAtIndex:38] intValue];
        malehalfBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:39] intValue];
        malefullBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:40] intValue];
        malesmaSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:41] intValue];
        malelarSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:42] intValue];
        malealcPop = [[values objectAtIndex:43] intValue];
        malehp = [[values objectAtIndex:44] intValue];
        malehc = [[values objectAtIndex:45] intValue];
        malebb = [[values objectAtIndex:46] intValue];
        maleaddUnit = [[values objectAtIndex:47] intValue];
        maleborg = [[values objectAtIndex:48] intValue];
        malesavedTenValue = [[values objectAtIndex:49] intValue];
        maleaddOne = [[values objectAtIndex:50] intValue];
        malepinLag = [[values objectAtIndex:51] intValue];
        malepinCid = [[values objectAtIndex:52] intValue];
        malehalfpinLag = [[values objectAtIndex:53] intValue];
        malehalfpinCid = [[values objectAtIndex:54] intValue];


        malesvdsmaWin = [[values objectAtIndex:55] intValue];
        malesvdmedWin = [[values objectAtIndex:56] intValue];
        malesvdlarWin = [[values objectAtIndex:57] intValue];
        malesvdhalfBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:58] intValue];
        malesvdfullBotWin = [[values objectAtIndex:59] intValue];
        malesvdsmaSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:60] intValue];
        malesvdlarSpi = [[values objectAtIndex:61] intValue];
        malesvdalcPop = [[values objectAtIndex:62] intValue];
        malesvdhp = [[values objectAtIndex:63] intValue];
        malesvdhc = [[values objectAtIndex:64] intValue];
        malesvdbb = [[values objectAtIndex:65] intValue];
        malesvdaddUnit = [[values objectAtIndex:66] intValue];

        malewarningmessage = [[values objectAtIndex:67] intValue];
        continueall = [[values objectAtIndex:68] intValue];
        continueFemale = [[values objectAtIndex:69] intValue];
        continueMale = [[values objectAtIndex:70] intValue];

        malesvdTotal = [[values objectAtIndex:71] intValue];
        malesvdpinLag = [[values objectAtIndex:72] intValue];
        malesvdpinCid = [[values objectAtIndex:73] intValue];

        ukOrUsa = [[values objectAtIndex:74] intValue];
        ukonce = [[values objectAtIndex:75] intValue];
        usaonce = [[values objectAtIndex:76] intValue];
        maleukonce = [[values objectAtIndex:77] intValue];
        maleusaonce = [[values objectAtIndex:78] intValue];


        [values release]; 
    }


    UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (applicationDidEnterBackground:)name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:myApp];

    if (continueMale == 0) {
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please read App info." message:@"Select the 'Info' button below." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
        [myAlert release];
        continueMale = 1;
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `,nil];` after the item at index 36. Remove it and the rest of your array elements should be  inserted properly.

Comment: @TJ15 You also seem to have an extra `*/` in your code. Are you sure it compiles exactly the way you showed us? Are there any other differences?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the code above to exactly what I am using from the last compile, it does read some of the data correctly but then fails. App runs without issue until data is saved.

Comment: Why don't you log the array you build and the array you load from the file.

Comment: @TJ15 In what way does it fail? Also, have you considered using [NSKeyedArchiver](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: @jtbandes The labels are updated with the wrong values, it appears as though the order is wrong but I am not sure how this could happen when using objectAtIndex. Each time the app is closed (info saved) the results appear more messed up. I think it is something to do with the save function. I have never used NSKeyedArchiver but was looking for a better way to store integers.